# Finding a specific element from a website using beautiful soup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to write a code that coverts money currencies into each other. To do so, I need the most recent updates of money currencies. I've chosen a website which displays them online. I want to find the desired currency (f.e. USD). I read a few articles about `Beautiful Soup`, but I'm not able to properly work with it. I've also checked similar questions on Stackoverflow.

Here's the part of HTML code of the currency website I see when I inspect the element:

[image]

I've marked down the part which says `270,693`. I want to get it with help of `soup.find()`, but I somehow can't get it right. I'm not really familiar with how it works.

Here's what I've tried, but I know it's not correct:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'https://english.tgju.org/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
rank = soup.find(#What_should I do here?!)
print(rank)
```

I really appreciate any of your helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://english.tgju.org/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')

rank = soup.find('tr', {'data-market-row':'sana_sell_usd'})['data-price']
print(rank)
```

Output:

```
270,639
```

Comment: or he could just read that from the data-price attr in tr

Comment: This is good, but I only want one number, not a long list of many, how can I make it more precise?

Comment: Which number do u want?

Comment: Right the one I've underlined. The USD currency rate.